# How to add Computer Name and User name using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, environment-variables

How can I use the computer name and username for each windows 7 and 10 computer on my network as variables to be entered into a table.

I am using a Table on a hidden sheet to log saves to a workbook. The files are opened from and saved to a network computer. I'd like to know who saved on each workbook

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("EDITS")
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table1")
Dim newrow As ListRow
Set newrow = tbl.ListRows.Add

'DIM SOME MORE OBJECTS
Dim computername, username As String
Dim ComputerNameLen As Long

computername = Environ("computer name") 'Get computer name
username = Environ("user name") 'Get user name


SavePrompt.Show

With newrow
    .Range(1) = Now
    .Range(2) = SavePrompt.TextBox1.Text
    .Range(3) = computername
    .Range(4) = username 

End With

Unload SavePrompt
Unload computername
Unload username
End Sub
```

Range(1) & Range(2) both fill out correctly but nothing appears for Ranges(3)&(4)

I think there is something wrong with my objects?

Comment: `environ("username")` and `environ("computername")`. No spaces.

Comment: I hadn't realised environ could be used like that, I always used an index and split the result e.g. `Environ(1)` give me `username=billy` - silly me!

Comment: When i do that i get a "Compile Error: Object Required". @cyboashu Specifically with "= username"

Comment: First properly declare you computername variable `Dim computername As String, username As String`. If you omit that `As String` you will end up with a variant which may cause some issues. It doesn't just pick up the type from the last variable in the `Dim` line.

Comment: @JNevill i changed my Dim lines to

    Dim computername As String
    Dim username As String
    computername = Environ("computername")
    username = Environ("username") 'Getting user name

Comment: @Kenny what is the full line you're getting the error on? in your comment 10 minutes ago you said it was on a line with `= username`?

Comment: i solved it with,

Dim computername As String
Dim username As String
computername = Environ("computername")
username = Environ("username")

thanks @JNevill. that last error was because of something leftover after trying something different and overlooking deleting a line when trying your solution.

Comment: If you need Active Directory stuff, look into GetObject("LDAP") etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("EDITS")
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table1")
Dim newrow As ListRow
Set newrow = tbl.ListRows.Add

'DIM SOME MORE OBJECTS
Dim computername As String
Dim username As String
computername = Environ("computername")
username = Environ("username") 

    SavePrompt.Show

With newrow
    .Range(1) = Now
    .Range(2) = SavePrompt.TextBox1.Text
    .Range(3) = computername
    .Range(4) = username

End With

Unload SavePrompt

End Sub
```